# How to split lengthy URI in php

Tags: php

I am sending bulk SMS with php API through a SMS gatway like this:

```
http://smsserviceprovider.com/sendsms.php?apikey=xxxx&text=testsms&mobiles=11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666....
```

(upto 1800 mobile numbers which is stored in `mysqldb`). But the service provider only allow me to send only 50 mobiles at once. So I have to send SMS in multiple times. How can I `split the parameter`mobiles like this

```
http://smsserviceprovider.com/sendsms.php?apikey=xxxx&text=testsms&mobiles=11111,22222
http://smsserviceprovider.com/sendsms.php?apikey=xxxx&text=testsms&mobiles=33333,44444
http://smsserviceprovider.com/sendsms.php?apikey=xxxx&text=testsms&mobiles=55555,66666....
```

My current function in php is

```
function send_sms($message, $numbers) {
        $apikey="xxxxx";
        $message=urlencode($message);
        $var = "apikey=".$apikey."&text=".$message."&mobiles=".$numbers";
        $curl=curl_init('http://smsserviceprovider.com/sendsms.php?'.$var);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $response=curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response; 
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even match what you say is your desired output. You use `mobiles=...`, but your code uses `phone=...`.

Comment: @Sherif Sorry, I have updated my question

Comment: Limit your query to 50 and generate your 36 URIs as you said you've 1800 numbers. Later you can execute them with a delay.

Comment: First, you should have a column in your phone number table or a separate table for identifying numbers that haven't been sms-ed. Then just repeat this: select 50 unsent numbers, send SMS, update status.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far to split `$numbers` or to read less numbers at a time from your database? Post that code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to build an array from your comma-separated list of phone numbers, using something like [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) and then group them into chunks of 50 using something like [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array-chunk). However, this does mean your function now has to make multiple requests instead of one due to this constraint. So in the following example I return an array of responses instead of just a single response.

```
function send_sms($message, $numbers) {
    $responses = [];
    $params = [
        'text'    => $message,
        'mobiles' => '',
        'apikey'  => 'xxxxx',
    ];

    $numbers = explode(',', $numbers);

    foreach(array_chunk($numbers, 50) as $numlist) {
        $params["mobiles"] = $numlist;
        $queryString = http_build_query($params);
        $responses[] = file_get_contents($url . $queryString);
    }
    return $responses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want.
But if you need mysql solution then you should go for LIMT statement in query.
for example :

```
$sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Mobiles LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0";
or 
$sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Mobiles LIMIT 0, 50";//offset, limit
```

Similar functionality can be done in retrieved array of 1800 mobile by using:

```
$sliced = array_slice($mobileArray, 0, 50)//array_slice($mobileArray, OFFSET, LIMIT);
```

You can go on changing offset in both implementations recursively. 
I hope this is ok to get started and extend it in PHP.